# What Stack Exchange Site Reputation Level Should be Given the Privilege to Up Vote One's Own Question?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, privileges, up-votes

I'm suggesting a new privilege of the ability to *up vote* one's own question after mucho reputation.

What Stack Exchange site reputation level should be given the privilege to *up vote* one's own question?

Comment: But why? -----------------

Comment: The ability to downvote your own questions would be more fitting.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but a red free hand 42 avatar, that's meta!

Comment: Well if you have an incredible amount of reputation and you have an incredible question and you think it's incredibly deserving of an _up vote_ then you should have the privilege of _up vote_ that question. @probablyPekka

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It should be mandatory. So all questions start at -1. Better yet. All questions should start at -4 so they don't show up on the homepage until someone upvotes them. :P:P:P:P:P:P:P

Comment: I'm suggesting we don't.

Comment: @java ignoring "having the right to", what positive effect would this have on the stack exchange system?

Comment: Best judge = MEDUH

Answer (score 26):

This would be somewhat pointless (well, worse).

I'd literally upvote every post I post if able, because:

- Naturally I think they're all useful
- Just to potentially increase the attention my post gets (and to keep up with others doing the same)
- To get reputation, if you were thinking that it would give you reputation

(and I'm sure everyone would do the same with their posts).

I say "worse" because:

- According to your proposal, only high-reputation users will be able to do this, so low-reputation users will be disadvantaged.
- Everyone who doesn't do this to all their posts will be disadvantaged (and if everyone does this to all your posts, why not just do this automatically to all posts?)

There's also the minor issue of users voting according to what score they think a post should have, as opposed to voting based on whether or not it's useful, or because other people are doing the same, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: I recently wanted to downvote a crappy link-only answer ... only to discover I wrote it 3 years ago.

Comment: @Bart I'm sure you thought it was useful 3 years ago.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm sure it was considered useful three years ago /grin